# how to speed up build time of an c++ eclipse project

Tags: linker, eclipse-cdt, static-linking

I have an eclipse CDT application which uses a number of external libraries. These libraries take a lot of time in the linking phase and the total build time shoots up. Is there any way out to improve on the build time?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: do you only want to speed up the linking phase or also other build parts?

Comment: OS: ubuntu 12.10. I would like to speed up the entire build process.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're running on VMWare might slow you down a bit.

Some ideas that come to mind:

- make sure you have VMWare tools installed
- increase the amount of RAM to your VM (the more, the better)
- use a ramdisk for your libraries (but might not do much good, since running on VMWare)
- use the [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) features of the compiler as much as possible, so that the libraries you're linking against have less exported symbols, making the linking stage less complicated. If they're libraries from the OS, not much you can do about it and they're probably optimized as such.
- (not very helpful) use a real machine for building. Virtualization takes its toll on an disk/cpu intensive operation, such as linking a lot of libraries.